# How to override Spring Boot dependencies default version?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

How to change Spring Boot dependencies default versions?
For example Spring Boot 1.4 uses Thymeleaf 2.1 version but recent version of Thymeleaf is 3.0. So how to change version 2.1 to 3.0?

Answer (score 25):

The answer provided by Andy only works when your POM inherits from `spring-boot-dependencies`. When `spring-boot-dependencies` is added through `dependencyManagement`, you have to [redefine](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using.import) all the artifacts that you want to override. Bummer!

This is also stated in the document referenced by Andy (it might have been added later).

Comment: Here is the reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.5/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using-parent-pom

Answer (score 23):

The documentation [describes how to do this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-dependency-versions).

Judging by the tags on the question, you're using Maven. You should add a property to your application's pom.xml to set the Thymeleaf version:

```
<properties>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.1.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
</properties>
```

There's also a [sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-thymeleaf3) that shows how to use Thymeleaf 3.0 with Spring Boot 1.4 that may be of interest.