# Introducing dependencies in other projects causes Maven to downgrade okhttp3 version

Tags: java, maven

I deploy my *maven* project to a *maven* private server. After introducing dependencies in other projects, the version of `okhttp3` changed from *4.7.2* to *3.14.9*

[The maven dependency of the deployed project：mdm-auth-spring-boot-starter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQJe6.png)

[Another project introduces mdm-auth-spring-boot-starter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVFnI.png)

Why has the version of `okhttp3` has changed?

My OS is *Win10*, *JDK_version-1.8.181*, *maven* version *3.6.3*

Reinstalling the system, *JDK* and *maven*, doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override Spring Boot dependencies default version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613498/how-to-override-spring-boot-dependencies-default-version)

Answer (score 4):

The `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.3.1-RELEASE` that you extend manages the version of `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp` to 3.14.9 via [spring-boot-dependencies](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.3.1.RELEASE/pom):

```
<okhttp3.version>3.14.9</okhttp3.version>
...
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
...
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>${okhttp3.version}</version>
      </dependency>
...
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

This is documented under [dependency management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-dependency-management):

> Each release of Spring Boot provides a curated list of dependencies that it supports. In practice, you do not need to provide a version for any of these dependencies in your build configuration, as Spring Boot manages that for you.

You'll need to either accept that, and work with that version, or set the `okhttp3.version` property in your project for the `okhtttp` version that you'd like to build with.

Comment: ndeed as you said，the okhttp3.version is now clearly specified in the project

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in transitive dependencies (some other dependency has a dependeny to okhttp3 3.14.9 and it can overriede 4.7.2 )
You can try to execute `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true`
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html
and find, which versions of okhttp3  you have,  and see which other dependency brought 3.14.9 version.